# HTML - Block not displaying as intended (embedded list)

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if any of you wonderful people would be able and willing to help a newbie? :D

I'm in very early stages, working on creating a navigation bar div:

```
    <div class="NavBar">
<ul>
<li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">News</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Test Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test Item 3</a></li>
    </ul></li>
<li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Process</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
<img src="C:\Users\Charlie\Creative Cloud Files\Logo_v4_(pink_background_no_border_no_text).png" height=40px, width=auto, align="right">
</div>
```

The CSS that goes with this is as follows:

```
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
}



ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding; 0;
}

ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ED1E79;
}

ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    display: block;
}

ul li a:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: #ED1E79;
    font-weight: bold;
}

ul li ul li {
    display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul li {
    vertical-align: top;
    float:left;
    display: block;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul li:hover ul li:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: #ED1E79;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.title {
    color: #ED1E79;
}

.NavBar {
    background-color: #ED1E79;
    height:40px;
    width:75%;
}

.active {
    background-color: #9e005d;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

My intention with this code was to be able to hover on one of the menu items (in the initial  tags) in order to display the sub-menu items (in the embedded  tags) so that they line up vertically. However, they do not as of yet line up as intended.

At the moment, the dropdown (on ul li hover) is displaying to the right of the 'About' section. I was wondering what the appropriate fix to such a problem would be (to get the dropdown to line up with the 'About' section vertically).

Comment: Although this isn't how I would do it (I don't recommend the use of float for positioning. I've used "display: inline-block" traditionally, but flexbox is the best solution these days), simply changing "float: left;" into "float: right;" for the submenu items is enough to make it work as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding; 0;
}
ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ED1E79;
  position:relative;
}
ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}
ul li a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: #ED1E79;
  font-weight: bold;
}
ul li ul{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%; 
  z-index: 1;
}
ul li:hover ul{
  display:block;
}
ul li ul li {
  vertical-align: top;
  float:left;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul li:hover ul li:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: #ED1E79;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.title {
  color: #ED1E79;
}
.NavBar {
  background-color: #ED1E79;
  height:40px;
  width:75%;
}
.active {
  background-color: #9e005d;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="NavBar">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Test Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Process</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <img src="C:\Users\Charlie\Creative Cloud Files\Logo_v4_(pink_background_no_border_no_text).png" height=40px, width=auto, align="right" alt="" />
  </ul>
</div>
```